# Why do apps from Android 2.1 stop working with 2.2?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-version

I've just updated my nexus one to 2.2. Now all of my (own and some from the market) apps throw exceptions and were closed.

It's weird, in the app I'm developing atm, there it displays only my start page with buttons, but when I tap on one button to fire an intent to another activity my app gets closed with an exception.

Yesterday before the update everything worked fine.

The same thing in my emulator:

I have two devices, one with API level 7 and one with level 8. Level 7 worked fine, but level 8 killed my app :(

What is the problem and how can I solve this? I'm desperatly trying to get it working again :(

I hope someone can help me fixing this

Comment: How about adding the exception message?

Comment: hi, i think I found out what the problem was...
indeed it had nothing to do with the version. The problem was the SD card. while connected to the pc as mass storage device, my app has no access to it...
*FAIL*

Comment: the strange thing is, after adding an api8-emulator, I can't access to the sdcard via DDMS...

Comment: Did you receive an update message and the system upgraded itself or did you do it manually?

Comment: poeschlorn, that was already the case before 2.2. When the SD card is mounted as mass storage, the phone cannot see it anymore. Note that this is exactly as if the user removed the SD card from the phone. Your app should still work in that case.

Comment: @poeschlorn btw, you may want to post your fix as an answer to the question and mark it as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, like in my comment above I write it right here as answer:

The problem was that the SD was mounted as mass storage device on my pc, while I was trying to access it by my app -> Error, because SD was not accessable from app

In fact, it had nothing to do with the version (see comment from Roman Guy). The problem just occured the first time, two days after I updated the device ;-)

I hope someone can benefit from my stupidness ;-)